# Finding one column in another column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel and I need to do the following:

I have one column which is in Sheet 1:

```
Contract 
    2004
    2005
```

I have one column which is in Sheet 2:

```
Customer Contract            Organization
AB002004                       200
AB002004                       300
AB002005                       400
```

I want my results Sheet which is Sheet 3 to look like this:

```
Contract       Customer Contract
2004           AB002004  
2004           AB002004  
2005           AB002005
```

Basically to explain in words, I want to Search the contract column from Sheet 1, find all occurrences of it that happen in Sheet 2 and create a new Sheet 3 that will have the contract along with the corresponding Customer Contract that ends with the 4 digit Contract.

Any clues on where to start would be appreciated. Would I use Vlookup in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use and modify the following accordingly.

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH("*"&A1,D:D,0))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Using your specifications above, try this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("*"&Sheet3!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Assuming the contract numbers are in Column A of `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

Comment: @pnuts: My answer is assuming that OP is alright with manually creating Sheet3, posting the contract numbers there, and just using a formula to get the customer contracts from Sheet2. I have enough juice to turn it into VBA, though. :D

Comment: Hey this is a great solution with only one caveat. The Customer Contract AB002004 appears twice for the 2004 contract and it's imperative that it appear twice too in the sheet3 where the results will be stored. With the above it only seems to give me one instance of AB002004 appearing.